# Display div 5 seconds after button click

Tags: html, jquery

I want to show a block 5 seconds after clicking the button. My current code doesn't work. What's the problem?

```js
if ($('#identify').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('block1').classList.remove('hide');
  }, 5000);
}));
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="identify" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 10px;">Identify</button>
<div class="slideRight expandUp hide" id="block1">Text Appears</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using JQuery removeAttr method rather than vanilla javascript use that and it should work https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: @Patch jQuery has functions specifically for manipulating classes, no need to mess with the entire attribute. `.removeClass()` will do it.

Comment: @DBS Yeah I guess it'll do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers in JS don't work as you're expecting; ie. by checking state in `if` conditions.

Instead you should attach event handler functions to the elements which will run when the specific event occurs. This is how your code should be structured:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#identify').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#block1').removeClass('hide');
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
#identify { padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="identify" class="btn btn-primary">Identify</button>
<div class="slideRight expandUp hide" id="block1">Text Appears</div>
```

Note the inclusion of a document.ready handler in the above code, and also moving the inline CSS in to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#identify').click(function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.getElementById('block1').classList.remove('hide');
                }, 5000);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will show taht div immediate and then it hide the text and then it reappers after 5 sec as in your question.

```
<script>
$('#identify').click(function() {
$("#block1").removeClass('hide');
setTimeout(function(){
$("#block1").addClass('hide');
}, 1000);  
setTimeout(function(){
$("#block1").removeClass('hide');
}, 6000);    
});
</script>
```